# How to edit a .conf file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My test.conf is like this:

```
First.Name: Abc
Age: 20
```

I want to update the .conf file by updating Name and age

```
First.Name: XYZ
Age: 30
```

Please note in my .conf I am using a semicolon (`:`) and not an equals (`=`) character for the key-value. Also, there is dot (`.`) character in the key.

Comment: 1. Semi colon is `;`,  colon is `:`. 2. Do you mean to edit the file with a text editor or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)'s `csv.reader` and `csv.writer`.

While the "**c**" in "**c**sv" does mean "**comma**"-delimited, the reader and writer objects can be configured to use a different delimiter, like in your case, make it use `":"` to be the delimiter (or to be exact, `": "` with an extra space).

##### Reading from a .conf file

```
In [15]: !cat test.conf
First.Name: Abc
Age: 20

In [16]: import csv

In [17]: with open("test.conf") as conf_file:
    ...:     reader = csv.reader(conf_file, delimiter=":", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    ...:     for row in reader:
    ...:         print(row)
    ...: 
['First.Name', ' Abc']
['Age', ' 20']
```

Each row is read and split by the `:` delimiter, and then the parts are returned as a list of strings. Note that the value has a space in front of it, since the reader splits right after `:`. You can tell the reader to ignore it by setting [`skipinitialspace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) to `True`:

```
In [32]: with open("test.conf") as conf_file:
    ...:     reader = csv.reader(conf_file, delimiter=":", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, skipinitialspace=True)
    ...:     for row in reader:
    ...:         print(row)
    ...: 
['First.Name', 'Abc']
['Age', '20']
```

You can then put them in a regular Python dictionary.

```
In [33]: with open("test.conf") as conf_file:
    ...:     reader = csv.reader(conf_file, delimiter=":", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, skipinitialspace=True)
    ...:     conf_data = {}
    ...:     for row in reader:
    ...:         key, value = row
    ...:         conf_data[key] = value
    ...: 

In [34]: conf_data
Out[34]: {'First.Name': 'Abc', 'Age': '20'}
```

##### Writing to a .conf file

Once the contents are now in a dictionary, you can then modify it as needed. The fact that the key has a dot (`.`) also doesn't matter anymore since it's part of a regular string.

```
In [34]: conf_data
Out[34]: {'First.Name': 'Abc', 'Age': '20'}

In [35]: conf_data["First.Name"] = "XYZ"

In [36]: conf_data["Age"] = "30"

In [37]: conf_data
Out[37]: {'First.Name': 'XYZ', 'Age': "30"}
```

Then use `csv.writer` to write the dict to a file (either the same file or to a different file, up to you). The [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) function accepts an iterable of values, so you need to transform the dict keys and values back to an iterable, such as a list:

```
In [39]: with open("output.conf", "w") as conf_file:
    ...:     writer = csv.writer(conf_file, delimiter=":", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    ...:     for key, value in conf_data.items():
    ...:         writer.writerow([key, value])
    ...: 

In [40]: !cat output.conf
First.Name:XYZ
Age:30
```

If you want to preserve the space after the `:`, you'll have to add that back manually by formatting the value:

```
In [41]: with open("output.conf", "w") as conf_file:
    ...:     writer = csv.writer(conf_file, delimiter=":", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    ...:     for key, value in conf_data.items():
    ...:         writer.writerow([key, f" {value}"])
    ...: 

In [42]: !cat output.conf
First.Name: XYZ
Age: 30
```